# Can hyperlink clicks be automated in Evolution and how

Tags: email, evolution

Is there any way to automatically click a link in an email from a specific recipient in Evolution, as the emails come in? Perhaps there is an extension that can be added, or possibly a macro? If not, is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can directly "click" links, but Evolution have [filters](https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/mail-filters.html.en) that can invoke [different actions](https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/mail-filters-actions.html.en). One of the action is `Pipe to Program`.

Create filter by going to: `Edit -> Message filters -> Add` and set it to filter emails from the address that you want. In `Then` section select `Pipe to Program` and select script to process your mail.

I would reccomend simple Python script to process the mails - it has to allow input to be piped into it. Example below (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1454400/499768) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6883094/499768)) should give you some idea how to achieve it. Obviously instead of logging urls to file you would have to open browser or just open it using [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.request.html) or similar.

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                                                                      
import fileinput
import re

f = open('a.out', 'a')

for line in fileinput.input():
  urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', line)
  for url in urls:
    f.write(url+"\n")
f.close()
```